# Handle popup automatically and click yes with "FindWindow" in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

can someone translate this code...

```
int iHandle = NativeWin32.FindWindow(null, "Security Alert");
NativeWin32.SetForegroundWindow(iHandle);
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("Y%");
```

...into VB.net ?

[image]

Because I'm not able to click on "Yes" on this "Security Alert" window (upper screenshot).

Comment: I do not believe that what you are trying to go is good practice. That box is there to inform the user of a problem with a security certificate. It is their choice not yours wetter or not to proceed.

Comment: ...that said, pinvoke.net has everything for all the WinAPI calls such as for `FindWindow`. `SetForegroundWindow` would appear to be their alias for `SetActiveWindow`

Comment: Just to mention... if user has another language installed then sending the letter `Y` could probably do nothing.

Comment: @MarkHall, actually the purpose of that is to access a physical network appliance using REST API. So there is no real security issue.

Comment: @Plutonix, I will have a look on pinvoke.net ;-)

Comment: @SysDragon, you're right and this is why I will sen ENTER key instead of Y.

Comment: @SkorPPio Then I'll edit my answer to use that key. Sorry, thought it was `Y`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function FindWindow(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As System.IntPtr
End Function

<Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function SetForegroundWindow(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr) As Long
End Function

Public Sub HandleWindows()
    Dim iPtr As Integer = FindWindow(Nothing, "MyWindow")
    SetForegroundWindow(iPtr)
    SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}")
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you can take the handle of the window with the process, something like:

```
Public Function GetWindowHandle() As Integer
    Dim proc As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK")(0)

    If proc IsNot Nothing AndAlso proc.MainWindowTitle.Equals("Security Alert") Then
        return proc.MainWindowHandle()
    End If

    return 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Very useful code thanks! The problem is that I'm facing this security alert into the "webbrowser1" control (Internet Explorer by default). And I'm still not able to catch the event that refers to this security alert. I also have to found what is the process ID. Anyway, thanks for these ideas !